# Are field extensions faithfully flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, extension-field

Is $\mathbb{C}$ a faithfully flat $\mathbb{R}$-module? In the general case, is it true that if $k$ is a field and $K$ is it's algebraic closure then $K$ is a faithfully flat $k$-module?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If $k$ is any field, then all $k$-modules are free, hence faithfully flat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All extensions of fields are faithfully flat.

You can use the criterion that every prime ideal of the small field
is the inverse image of one in the large field.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, where can I find these cretierion?

Comment: @matemagreek On  Wikipedia for a start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module